# Specialize templated function in class

Tags: c++, templates

I am currently getting into templates and I am trying to fully specialize a class function here in my class (only relevant code):

```
class item_t
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void set(const std::string &key, const T &value);
    template<>
    void set(const std::string &key, const std::string &value);
};
```

which will result in this compiler error (gcc 6.3.0):

```
Fehler: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class base::data::item_t’
  template<>
           ^
```

What am I missing here? From what I understood, it is not possible to partially specialize a function template, but this is a full specialization.

Comment: There are also rules about where that specialization may appear. Listen to the error, define it outside the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot explicitly specialize a template member function inside the class definition. You have to do it outside *(in a namespace scope)*:

```
class item_t
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void set(const std::string &key, const T &value);

};

template<>
void item_t::set<std::string>(const std::string &key, const std::string &value)
{
}
```

In your particular use case, you don't even need a specialization - an overload will work just fine:

```
template<class T>
void set(const std::string &key, const T &value);

void set(const std::string &key, const std::string &value);
```